# Create an array based off of a serialized object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a JavaScript object like this: (it has come from serialized form data)

```
{
  "my_data[options][0][foo]": "a", 
  "my_data[options][0][bar]": "b",
  "my_data[options][1][foo]": "c",
  "my_data[options][1][bar]": "d",
  "my_data[options][2][foo]": "e",
  "my_data[options][2][bar]": "f"
}
```

How can I manipulate it so I end up with:

```
[
  {foo: "a", bar: "b"},
  {foo: "c", bar: "d"},
  {foo: "e", bar: "f"}
]
```

While there are only 3 objects here, in practice there will be an unknown number of objects.

**Edit:**
A little more info.

The reason I'm doing this is because I need to get data from form elements on the page.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="my_data[something]" />
  <input type="text" name="unrelated_thing" />
```

Within the form, I have a matrix full of fields like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="my_data[options][0][foo]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="my_data[options][0][bar]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="my_data[options][1][foo]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="my_data[options][1][bar]" /></td>
  </tr>
  etc...
</table>
```

I need to get just the data from the matrix (`my_data[options]`) in an array so I can iterate over it.

I think serializing the form and then manipulating the data would be faster than iterating over each table row and then over each field.

Comment: That object syntax looks odd.  Is that the *exact* syntax you have?  Is that in a string or a file?  Because that's not a "JavaScript object", unless the keys are literally `"my_data[options][0][foo]"`.

Comment: I've wrapped the keys in quotes. They are indeed the key names.

Comment: I would seriously consider getting the form as some Object directly instead of this mangled format with Strings that again has to be translated to an Object. Otherwise, you could eval() the keys or do some String searching in them using .indexOf() and .substr()

Comment: Okay, good advice. Might just start this over.

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var res = [];
for(var i in mydata[options]) {
    res.push({foo: i[foo], bar: i[bar]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just iterating over the`tr`s and then the `input`s inside.
I used a `str.replace` with a regex to strip out the appropriate parts of the `name` attribute.